# WebGL geometry interactions

Tags: geometry, 3d, shader, webgl

I have a dynamic surface in WebGL, that is animated in vertex shader. I want other objects to interact with this surface (for example, an object riding on dynamic terrain). What's the best way to do this? Should all these calculations be done on CPU? Is there a way to calculate this stuff on GPU?

Basically, what I want is vertex shader with access to other (already transformed) vertices -- that would be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can do this on the shader, unfortunately. The closest I can think of is passing in a second set of attributes, *but* the vertex count would have to be identical, and you could only validate one vertex of one model against a vertex with the same index of the other model (because you have no way of iterating through them all). Somehow, I don't think this is what you're looking for.

Your best bet is to implement these sorts of things (collision detection, for instance) on the CPU. It's very slow in JavaScript, and you'll need to think long and hard about the best algorithm to use for your scene, but it's the only thing I can think of that would actually work.

A good start would be to use spatial partitioning (examples: [octree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree), [BSP -- binary space partitioning -- tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning)). I've not done any sort of benchmarking, yet, but I have a hunch BSP trees would be more effective than octrees in most JavaScript scenes. There are often fewer checks to make overall, and potentially much less recursion. Also, BSP trees afford you the nearly unique ability to process geometry from back-to-front or front-to-back relative to any arbitrary point in space without having to constantly sort and re-sort the geometry. The drawback to BSP trees (and octrees to a lesser, but still nontrivial, extent) is that their geometry must remain static. That is, moving individual triangles on the fly doesn't work all that well with these trees, because then the geometry *does* have to be re-sorted. I don't think the static nature of spatial partitioning is a particularly troublesome issue if your meshes' animations are relatively simple, slight and predictable (such as a flag waving in the wind), but if they are more complex (such as a crumbling building or falling rocks), then these types of spatial partitions may not be viable for you at all.

Update: If your models consist of part-static and part-dynamic triangles, such as windmills (whose towers are static and fins are dynamic), then you could use spatial partitioning for the static parts, so that if you only take unnecessary performance hits for dynamic triangles, and reap the benefits of spatial partitioning for those triangles that aren't moving too much.

Update: Actually, there is one way you might be able to "kinda" do this at least partly on the shader. Specifically in reference to your example of an object riding on dynamic terrain, you could feasibly render that dynamic terrain to an offscreen framebuffer, then plot the object's position onto the same framebuffer, and use readpixels() to read in the height of the terrain at that position. This would only work for height maps, and the framebuffer would obviously need to be updated every time the terrain changes (if ever). However, it'd be a relatively simple way to see how high the object should be positioned on dynamic terrain without having to do the terrain generation itself on the CPU. This wouldn't be true collision detection though, and the object would still be subject to other issues (like having one wheel on or under the terrain and one wheel in midair). You could work around these issues but the solution would be nontrivial, probably involving multiple checks against the framebuffer data.